Powers of 2 among the terms of a linear recurrence sequence
I seek to determine which terms of the sequence $a$ defined by
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
(a_0,a_1)=(1,8)\\
a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}-a_n
\end{array}
\right.
$$
are powers of $2$.
See OEIS.
A computer investigation suggests that only $a_0$ and $a_1$ are powers of $2$, but I am unable to prove it.
Unless I am mistaken, I have managed to demonstrate (see below$^\star$) that if $k$ and $n$ are natural numbers, then
$$
a_{n+2^k}\equiv a_n+2^k\;(\text{mod} \,2^{k+1}).
$$
From this, it is not difficult to deduce that for any natural number $k$, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $2^k \;|\; a_n$.
The following table indicates, for the first values of the natural number $k$, the smallest value of the natural number $n$ such that $2^k\;|\;a_n$ :
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
k&n\\
\hline
1&1\\
\hline
2&1\\
\hline
3&1\\
\hline
4&9\\
\hline
5&25\\
\hline
6&25\\
\hline
7&25\\
\hline
8&25\\
\hline
9&25\\
\hline
10&25\\
\hline
\end{array}
\;\;\;\;\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
k&n\\
\hline
11&1049\\
\hline
12&3097\\
\hline
13&3097\\
\hline
14&11289\\
\hline
15&27673\\
\hline
16&60441\\
\hline
17&125977\\
\hline
18&125977\\
\hline
19&125977\\
\hline
20&650265\\
\hline
\end{array}
\;\;\;\;\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
k&n\\
\hline
21&1698841\\
\hline
22&1698841\\
\hline
23&1698841\\
\hline
24&10087449\\
\hline
25&10087449\\
\hline
26&43641881\\
\hline
27&110750745\\
\hline
28&110750745\\
\hline
29&379186201\\
\hline
30&916057113\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

$(^\star)$ Let $u$ and $v$ be the sequences of integers defined by $(u_1, v_1) = (6, -1)$ and, for any integer $k > 0$,
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u_{k+1} = 2u_k(3u_k + v_k) \\
v_{k+1} = v_k^2 - u_k^2
\end{array}
\right..$$
These sequences are designed so that for all integers $k > 0$ and $n \geq 0$,
$$a_{n+2^k} = u_k a_{n+1} + v_k a_n.$$
Using mathematical induction, it can be proven that for any integer $k > 0$,
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u_k \equiv 2^k \; (\text{mod}\, 2^{k+1}) \\
v_k \equiv 1 + 2^k \; (\text{mod}\, 2^{k+1})
\end{array}
\right..$$
It is then easy to deduce that for all integers $k > 0$ and $n \geq 0$,
$$a_{n+2^k} \equiv a_n + 2^k \; (\text{mod}\, 2^{k+1}).$$

I think I understand the proof, thanks. Earlier I misread your claim as implying that the period modulo $2^{k+1}$ would be $2^k$ but in fact your findings confirm that the period is $2^{k+1}.$

Please don't use "Edit: More stuff."  Instead, revise your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Revise and correct incorrect statements, introduce material in the logical order, etc.  No need to mark what has changed -- we have revision history for that.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755

It might help to know that the characteristic roots are $\alpha,\beta=3\pm2\sqrt{2}$, which is irrational.

The linked entry in the OEIS shows that the given sequence is the even part the of Chebyshev sequence with Diophantine property $b_n^2 - 8\cdot a_n^2 = 17$. In particular, $8a_n^2+17$ is a square for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Assuming $a_n=2^k$, we obtain a solution to the equation \begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}2^{m}+17=n^2\end{equation} with $m=2k+3$.

But this equation is well-studied. A reference is
Tzanakis, Nicholas. "On the Diophantine Equation $y^2-D=2^k$", in: Journal of Number Theory, 17 (1983), pp. 144-164. Online available here.
They show (see the Corollary on p. 151) that the only integral solutions of $(\ast)$ have $m=3,5,6,9$. So we must have $k=0,1$ or $3$. The first and last value correspond to $a_0=1$ and $a_1=8$, while $a_n=2$ has no solution, which can easily be observed by monotonicity. Thus $a_0$ and $a_1$ are indeed the only powers of $2$ among the $(a_n)_n$.
